# Tensorflow Keras value error sample size is not divisible when using 2 or more GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

I built my model using tensorflow and keras and it was working well using 1 GPU but when I tried to use 2 GPUs with tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(), it returns the following error:

> W0609 17:19:33.146776 140696832288576 training_arrays.py:289] Your dataset ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 2126 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/worker/Pycharm_Project/Main_DL.py", line 270, in 
> loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x=X_train, y=Y_train)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 904, in evaluate
> callbacks=callbacks)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py", line 160, in evaluate_distributed
> mode=ModeKeys.TEST)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py", line 475, in get_input_params
> 'batch size %s.' % (num_samples, global_batch_size))
> ValueError: The number of samples 106266 is not divisible by batch size 32.

I defined my model as:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    with self.tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_default():
        with self.tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config).as_default():
            with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope()):

                x = Input(shape=(800, 6, 1), name='X')
                self.y_ = self.create_model(x)
                self.scope()

                model = Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[self.y_])
                model.compile(loss=tf.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=self.optimizer, metrics=[self.metrics])

                print(model.input)
                model.summary()
                print(model.output)

    return model
```

and I'm running it with the following lines:

```
    with self.tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_default():
        with self.tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config).as_default():
            for epoch in range(100):
                hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
                loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x=X_train, y=Y_train)
                Y_train_predict = model.predict(x=X_train)
```

I have tried changing batch size and using steps_per_epoch instead of batch_size as follows:

```
batch_size = 32
steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // batch_size
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, verbose=1)
```

or

```
batch_size = 32
steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(len(X_train) / batch_size)
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, verbose=1)
```

I expected the sample size is now divisible. However, neither of them were successful.